# How to retrieve value in code behind from input type time in c#

Tags: c#, html

I have `<input type="time">` control but when i enter time(2:30PM) i'm getting the value in code behind like (1970-01-01T08:30:00.000Z) date with time in another format. how can i capture only time in giving format.

aspx:

```
<input type="time" value="{{data.EndTime}}"/>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.Save = function () {           
        var Data1 = $scope.catureddatafromUI;        

        var dataJsonString = JSON.stringify({
            arrdata1: Data1          
        });        
        var post = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: dataJsonString,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });
```

capturing JS data in list:

```
List<CommitConfigurationEntities>  arrdata1)
```

getting like date with time (1970-01-01T08:30:00.000Z).

how can i capture only time from input type time given format.

Comment: What do you want to do with the time when you've got it? Do you just need to redisplay it, or do you need to do a calculation with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a 'time' in C#, only DateTime (which you have) and TimeSpan (which you could use to express 'two and a half hours' but isn't what you want here).

When you convert a DateTime to a string, you should supply a format. If you don't (e.g. when looking at it in the debugger) you get the default, as you've seen.

To get just the time part of your DateTime, you could give it a format like this:

```
data.EndTime.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

The full list of magic letters that you can use in a date string format is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Note that this gives you a string that looks like a time, but it's not much use except to display to a person.

If you want something you can use in code, you could access the integer parts of the date like this:

```
var hour = data.EndTime.Hour;
```